# IIS or Apache Web Server Authentication with PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, iis

I have IIS and Apache Web Server set up on Windows 10 with PHP and curl. The following code works fine.

```
<?php

  $url = "http://domain.com";

  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //Timeout after 30 seconds
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); //Get status code

  $response = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);

  echo $response;

?>
```

When I add authentication, it does not work.

```
<?php

  $username = "username";
  $password = "password";
  $url = "https://domain.com/api/v2/orders/count";

  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //Timeout after 30 seconds
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

  $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); //Get status code

  $response = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);

  echo $response;

?>
```

This code works fine when I run it on my GoDaddy server.

The code is located at http://localhost/test.php
I have PHP NTS 7.0.13 and cURL 7.51.0
IIS is set up as FastCGI

Answer (score 0):

The CA Certification was not set up.

- Go to [pathToYourPHP]\extras\ssl
- Create a file called cacert.pem
- Go to [CA certificates extracted from Mozilla](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)
- Click on cacert.pem
- Copy the contents and put it in your cacert.pem
- In php.ini, set the path to curl.cainfo = "[pathToYourPHP]\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"

Note: This can also be bypassed by adding curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE)